Computer can't access Internet through USB tether
My phone is a Motorola G13 with Android 13. My computer is a Thinkpad W541 with Debian 12. I'm trying to access Internet on the computer through the phone's 4G. I've tried to use the phone as a wifi hotspot, and I've tried to share the connection through USB.
In both case, the computer connects to the local network correctly. The computer gets an IP address and a DNS server through DHCP. I can ping the DNS server from the computer. On the phone, I can access websites through the data.
However, if I try to ping an external IP from the computer, I get a "network unreachable" error. Same with curl, same with any other protocol I could think of. Same after booting up the computer with a Ubuntu Live USB stick. Both through wifi and through USB tether.
From all this, I'm inclined to think that there is some issue on the phone, that prevents the packets to be properly routed from the wifi/usb network, toward the 4g network. However, I have no idea how to actually find and fix the issue. I have already tried to change all the relevant settings I could find, and did a factory reset on the phone. None of that had any visible effect. I couldn't find any relevant help through googling either.
Any suggestion would be appreciated.

USB tether interface :
curl --interface enx1e8d3a3d4e80 1.1.1.1
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 1.1.1.1 port 80 after 1 ms: Couldn't connect to server

ethernet interface :
curl --interface enp0s25 1.1.1.1
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>cloudflare</center>
</body>
</html>


EDIT : I've tried with a Windows 10 computer, and the network panel tells me "No Internet access : Your device is connected and can access other devices on your local network, but may not be able to reach the Internet." So the issue is definitely from the phone, not the Debian computer.

EDIT : To answer comments :

Ping the gateway (your cell phone) :

this works fine.

verify DNS resolution

the dns answers, but the answer doesn't give an ip

Have you tried another tether method, like WiFi hotspot

Exact same results as usb tether, as far as I can tell

another (friends) device with a similar plan/carrier

I haven't any on hand, I'll try to see if I can find one.

Sounds like your carrier is blocking tethering... Does your cellular service include tethering?

I don't see anything saying that it doesn't, and the carrier's help page includes instruction to turn on the wifi hotsport on various phone brands.

Try something more simple then... You said you are getting DHCP... is it complete with IP, subnet mask, gateway, and DNS servers? If so, verify connectivity to each step... Ping the gateway (your cell phone), ping an IP address directly (8.8.8.8), ping your DNS server, verify DNS resolution... You need to know where it is failing. The issue here is you can't verify the phone is working OR the cellular provider is supporting tethering on your plan. Have you tried another tether method, like WiFi hotspot or another (friends) device with a similar plan/carrier?
